# imagecreatefrompng not working

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to create thumbnails of images, but I found that only JPG images can be converted into thumbnails by using the code below; it doesn't work with PNG and GIF. What am I doing wrong?

```
function createThumbs( $pathToImages,$pathToThumbs,$thumbWidth,$fname)
    {
      // open the directory
     // $dir = opendir( $pathToImages );


        // parse path for the extension
        $info = pathinfo($pathToImages);

        // continue only if this is a JPEG image
        //if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' )
        //{
          //echo "Creating thumbnail for {$fname} <br />";

            echo strtolower($info['extension']);
            switch(strtolower($info['extension'])){
                case 'jpg':
                        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("{$pathToImages}" );
                    break;
                case 'gif':
                        $img = imagecreatefromgif("{$pathToImages}" );
                    break;
                case 'png':
                        $img = imagecreatefrompng("{$pathToImages}" );
                    break;
                default:
                        die("ERROR: FILE TYPE DOES NOT SUPPORT");
                    break;
            }
          // load image and get image size

          $width = imagesx( $img );
          $height = imagesy( $img );

          // calculate thumbnail size
          $new_width = $thumbWidth;
          $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );

          // create a new temporary image
          $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

          // copy and resize old image into new image
          imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

          // save thumbnail into a file
          imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" );
          chmod("{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}",777);


    }
}
```

Comment: Please define what "does not work" means. Which of your `case` statements is executed, what works and what doesn't, any errors?

Comment: Exactly how are you calling this function?  From the variable names it looks to me as if `$pathToImages` should be a PATH, and the filename should be in `$fname`.  Is `$pathToImages` actually a filename?  And yes, let us know what errors you see.

Comment: It not creating thumbnail for png and gif images. However jpg thumnail images are producing.I am calling function as below :         createThumbs("../images/sliders/".$image1_newname,"../images/sliders/thumbs/",570,$image1_newname); 
  chmod("../images/sliders/thumbs/".$image1_newname,777);

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are facing is due to this line:

```
// save thumbnail into a file
imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" );
```

PHP imagejpeg will save the image as Jpeg.

What you need is to utilize the appropriated function to save each file type. Also you need to control the output file type extension, if not a *Joint Photographic Experts Group* file, `.jpeg` will not be appropriated.

### Dealing with the file extension

There are some good examples on the comments for the [PHP image_type_to_extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-extension.php)!

### Dealing with the save process

**imagewbmp**

```
// Save the image as a WBMP
imagewbmp( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" . '.wbmp' );
```

[imagewbmp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagewbmp.php) outputs or save a WBMP version of the given image.

**imagegif**

```
// Save the image as a GIF
imagegif( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" . '.gif' );
```

[imagegif()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) creates the GIF file in filename from the image image.

**imagepng**

```
// Save the image as a PNG
imagepng( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" . '.png' );
```

[imagepng](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) — Output a PNG image to either the browser or a file.

Answer (score -1):

```
        $new_images = $_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];

        $width = 400; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
        $size = GetimageSize($images);
        $height = round($width * $size[1] / $size[0]);

        list($origwidth, $origheight, $origtype, $origattr) = getimagesize($images);
        $origfiletype = image_type_to_extension($origtype, true);
        // $filetype includes the dot.            
        $supported = array('.jpeg', '.png', '.gif');
        //check file type
        if (in_array($origfiletype, $supported)) {
            if ('.jpeg' == $origfiletype) {
                $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($images);
            } else if ('.png' == $origfiletype) {
                try {
                    $images_orig = ImagecreateFromPNG($images);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                    exit;
                }
            } else if ('.gif' == $origfiletype) {
                try {
                    $images_orig = ImagecreateFromGIF($images);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                    exit;
                }
            }

            $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
            $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
            $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
            ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width + 1, $height + 1, $photoX, $photoY);
            ImageJPEG($images_fin, dirname(__FILE__) . "/gallery/" . $new_images, $jpeg_quality);
            ImageDestroy($images_orig);
            ImageDestroy($images_fin);
```

Comment: Please provide some sort of explanation of how this is supposed to help, rather than just posting a block of code.